# How to check network port(ex 9997,8089) avalability using command prompt in windows server?

Tags: networking, port

How to check the network port availability , in windows server as well as Linux and AIX servers

Comment: Use `netstat -an`

Comment: I don't want to look all the running ports just want to check the availability of only 1 port

Comment: Use grep(unix) or find(Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I found a two solutions for my problem:

`for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| findstr 9000') do tasklist /FI "PID eq %a`"

***or alternatively:***

```
echo off & (for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| findstr urportnum') do tasklist /NH /FI "PID eq %a") & echo on
```